# Install Erlang with asdf on Mac M1 monterrey fails

Tags: erlang, apple-m1, asdf

I tried to install Erlang `25.0.3` with `asdf` on a Monterrey mac M1, with the following command:

```
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--without-javac --with-ssl=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" asdf install erlang latest
```

It fails with the following error message:

```
Build failed.
=== Leaving application mnesia
=== Entering application crypto
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `opt'.
 MAKE   opt
make[4]: aarch64-apple-darwin21.2.0/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `aarch64-apple-darwin21.2.0/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: *** [opt] Error 2
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

Is there a specific configuration to adapt to mac M1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. I booted my M1 with a time machine backup from a macbook pro intel and you need to reinstall homebrew. I followed these instructions on Github and it worked:

https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang/issues/207#issuecomment-883216342

I had to run directly

```
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--with-ssl=`brew --prefix openssl` --without-javac --disable-debug" asdf install erlang 25.0.3
```

instead of putting it in the `.zshrc`